Bulk update ADObject owners/permissions
In 2021 we migrated away from our on-premises Exchange server to Google Workspace.  We have then migrated servers we needed from on-premises to Azure, but as the exchange server was no longer needed for email it was deleted and not migrated.
In the main this is not an issue, everyone uses Gmail on their phones and the website on their PC's.
However we are no starting to see some staff who had been here a long time leave the company, and as such when we go to delete their AD accounts, we are having issues as there are a number of ExchangeActiveSyncDevice linked to their accounts.  These need to be removed before they can be deleted.
To do this we need to change ownership of the objects from our old exchange server to the person attempting to remove them, then come out and then add Full Control permissions to that object before we can delete them.  In some cases there are 10 or more devices per account.
I have been able to get a list of objects using this script
get-adobject -Filter "ObjectClass -eq 'msExchActiveSyncDevice' -or ObjectClass -eq 'msExchActiveSyncDevices'" -searchbase "OU=User Accounts,DC=v2c-ad,DC=org,DC=uk" | Export-CSV "C:\Users\User123\Documents\objects.csv" -notypeinformation

I have then run a script I found here from several years back
` Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$list = Import-CSV C:\Users\User123\Documents\objects.csv

forEach ($item in $list) {
    $adobj = $item.objectGUID
    Remove-ADObject -Identity $adobj -Confirm:$False
}`

This works, but only if I have previously changed permissions.  It appears to be changing the permissions that is now the time consuming part.  Is it possible to change owner to User123 and give full permissions to User123 so that the 2nd script can be run?  It looks like there are about 550 objects to delete, so doing it individually will be a real pain.
Any help/advise would be greatly appreciated.

You may try dsacls.exe (downloadable via RSAT) or import and load Active Directory Powershell Module to get-set permissions using "AD" Drive (like C:\ or D:\ drives" cmdlets. For example to list AD permissions:     get-acl -Path "AD:cn=user1,cn=users,DC=lab1,DC=lab" |  fl *
